# Delay in Updating UILabel from API call

Tags: swift, multithreading, uilabel, nsurlsession, nsoperationqueue

I am updating my UILabels from an API Call. I have an API Client file which pulls the needed information and then passes it over to the DataStore and then parses through the information and then creates movie Objects. The collectionViewController accesses the information without a problem but when it passes the information to the next view controller, a problem occurs. The information does not appear on the view controller and then when I click back in the information will appear. There is some sort of delay in the information from the API Client or something which I can't seem to figure out.

```
//Second API call to get information for the Second View Controller (Detail View Controller)
    class func getDescriptiveMovieResultsFromSearch(movieID: String, completion:(NSDictionary)-> ())
    {
        var descriptiveDictionary: [String: String] = [:]

        let searchURL = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=\(movieID)&?plot=short"

        let nsurl = NSURL(string: searchURL)
        //convert the url into an NSURL

        guard let unwrappedNSURL = nsurl else {print("ERROR OCCURRED HERE"); return}
        //unwrap the nsurl using guard let

        //let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: unwrappedNSURL)
        //creation of the request

        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        //By Default everythiing is a GET request if you are getting information and you don't need it
        //request has an HTTPMethod of type "GET" to obtain information

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let unwrappedData = data else {print("Error occurred here"); return}

            if let responseDictionary = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(unwrappedData, options: []) as? NSDictionary
            {
                let castedResponseDictionary = responseDictionary as? [String : String]

                guard let unwrappedResponseDictionary = castedResponseDictionary else {print("This did not work!"); return}

                descriptiveDictionary = unwrappedResponseDictionary

            }
            completion(descriptiveDictionary)
    }
        task.resume()
    }

//MovieDataStore function to parse through the information 
/Second API Call
    func getDescriptiveMovieInformationWith(movie: Movie, Completion: (Bool) -> ())
    {
        guard let unwrappedimdbID = movie.imdbID else {print("AN ERROR OCCURRED HERE"); return}
        OMDBAPIClient.getDescriptiveMovieResultsFromSearch(unwrappedimdbID) { (descriptiveResponseDictionary) in

            let desMovieDirector = descriptiveResponseDictionary["Director"] as? String
            let desMovieWriters = descriptiveResponseDictionary["Writer"] as? String
            let desMovieActors = descriptiveResponseDictionary["Actors"] as? String
            let desMovieShortPlot = descriptiveResponseDictionary["Plot"] as? String
            let desMovieimbdRating = descriptiveResponseDictionary["imdbRating"] as? String

            //unwrapping each of the of the json information
            guard let
                unwrappedDesMovieDirector = desMovieDirector,
                unwrappedDesMovieWriters = desMovieWriters,
                unwrappedDesMovieActors = desMovieActors,
                unwrappedDesMovieShortPlot = desMovieShortPlot,
                unwrappedDesMovieimbdRating = desMovieimbdRating

                else {print("AN ERROR OCCURRED HERE!"); return}

                movie.director = unwrappedDesMovieDirector
                movie.writers = unwrappedDesMovieWriters
                movie.actors = unwrappedDesMovieActors
                movie.shortPlot = unwrappedDesMovieShortPlot
                movie.imdbRating = unwrappedDesMovieimbdRating

                print("******************************************")
                print("Movie Director: \(movie.director)")
                print("Movie writers: \(movie.writers)")
                print("Movie actors: \(movie.actors)")
                print("Movie shortPlot: \(movie.shortPlot)")
                print("Movie imdbRating: \(movie.imdbRating)")
                print("******************************************")
            //Completion(true)
            Completion(true)
        }

    }

//Detail View Controller 
/Second API Call
    func getDescriptiveMovieInformationWith(movie: Movie, Completion: (Bool) -> ())
    {
        guard let unwrappedimdbID = movie.imdbID else {print("AN ERROR OCCURRED HERE"); return}
        OMDBAPIClient.getDescriptiveMovieResultsFromSearch(unwrappedimdbID) { (descriptiveResponseDictionary) in

            let desMovieDirector = descriptiveResponseDictionary["Director"] as? String
            let desMovieWriters = descriptiveResponseDictionary["Writer"] as? String
            let desMovieActors = descriptiveResponseDictionary["Actors"] as? String
            let desMovieShortPlot = descriptiveResponseDictionary["Plot"] as? String
            let desMovieimbdRating = descriptiveResponseDictionary["imdbRating"] as? String

            //unwrapping each of the of the json information
            guard let
                unwrappedDesMovieDirector = desMovieDirector,
                unwrappedDesMovieWriters = desMovieWriters,
                unwrappedDesMovieActors = desMovieActors,
                unwrappedDesMovieShortPlot = desMovieShortPlot,
                unwrappedDesMovieimbdRating = desMovieimbdRating

                else {print("AN ERROR OCCURRED HERE!"); return}

                movie.director = unwrappedDesMovieDirector
                movie.writers = unwrappedDesMovieWriters
                movie.actors = unwrappedDesMovieActors
                movie.shortPlot = unwrappedDesMovieShortPlot
                movie.imdbRating = unwrappedDesMovieimbdRating

                print("******************************************")
                print("Movie Director: \(movie.director)")
                print("Movie writers: \(movie.writers)")
                print("Movie actors: \(movie.actors)")
                print("Movie shortPlot: \(movie.shortPlot)")
                print("Movie imdbRating: \(movie.imdbRating)")
                print("******************************************")
            //Completion(true)
            Completion(true)
        }

    }
```

//detail view Controller
override func viewDidLoad() {

```
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    self.yearLabel.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    self.directorLabel.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    self.writersLabel.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    self.actorsLabel.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    self.shortPlotLabel.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    self.imdbIDLabel.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    self.typeLabel.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    self.imdbRating.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    stackViewLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackViewLabel.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.topImage.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).active = true
    stackViewLabel.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.00).active = true
    stackViewLabel.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.50).active = true
    stackViewLabel.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leftAnchor).active = true

    //unwrapped Movie Object
    guard let unwrappedMovieObject = movieObject else {print("AN ERROR OCCURRED HERE!"); return}

    self.store.getDescriptiveMovieInformationWith(unwrappedMovieObject) { (isWorking) in
        if isWorking {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            guard let unwrappedPosterURL = unwrappedMovieObject.posterURL else {print("AN ERROR OCCURRED HERE"); return}
            if unwrappedPosterURL == "N/A"{
            self.topImage.image = UIImage.init(named: "star_PNG1592")
            }
            else {
                if let url = NSURL(string: unwrappedPosterURL){
                    if let data  = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
                        //print("I have an image to display")
                        self.topImage.image = UIImage.init(data: data)
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.titleLabel.text = unwrappedMovieObject.title
                self.yearLabel.text = unwrappedMovieObject.year
                self.imdbIDLabel.text = unwrappedMovieObject.imdbID
                self.typeLabel.text = unwrappedMovieObject.type

                guard let
                    unwrappedDirector = unwrappedMovieObject.director,
                    unwrappedWriters = unwrappedMovieObject.writers,
                    unwrappedActors = unwrappedMovieObject.actors,
                    unwrappedShortPlot = unwrappedMovieObject.shortPlot,
                    unwrappedRating = unwrappedMovieObject.imdbRating

                else {print("PROPERTIES WERE UNWRAPPED"); return}

                    self.directorLabel.text = unwrappedDirector
                    self.writersLabel.text = unwrappedWriters
                    self.actorsLabel.text = unwrappedActors
                    self.shortPlotLabel.text = unwrappedShortPlot
                    self.imdbRating.text = unwrappedRating
            }
        }

        else{

            print("AN ERROR OCCURRED HERE")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the Detail View Controller using the information from the DataStore to update the UILabel

Comment: Would appreciate any input! Thanks!

Comment: Put a debugger and see if the label update is being called when you get response from your block function.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
```

I'm not sure what callback queue the sharedSession uses, If its not the main thread you will need to

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   completion(descriptiveDictionary)
}
```

Comment: Problem existed in this                                                                                          if let responseDictionary = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(unwrappedData, options: []) as? NSDictionary and it should have been let responseDictionary = try? NSJonsSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(unwrappedData, options:[]) as! NSdicitonary